# Como limitar o upload de uma imagem através de seu tamanho em pixels?

Tags: imagem, input, validação, vue.js

Estou fazendo uma aplicação com VueJS e tenho um input de upload de imagens e quero definir um limite de tamanho de imagem para upload, não em KB ou MB, mas sim com base eu seus pixels ou seja, somente permitir o upload se a imagem respeitar o limite de pixels.

Ex.: 320x280

Se a imagem for maior que isso emitir um aviso que não pode ser imagens maiores que o tamanho estipulado.

Aqui tenho a função em JS que recebe a imagem

```
carregarFoto (e) {
  var arquivo = e.target.files
  if (!arquivo[0]) {
    return
  }
  var data = new FormData()
  data.append('media', arquivo[0])
  var reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = (e) => {
    this.foto = e.target.result
    console.log(this.camposForm.foto)
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(arquivo[0])
},
```

Aqui está o input:

```
<input @change="carregarFoto" type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*">
```

Já tentei usar esse [link](https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/333720-validar-imagem-antes-do-upload/), mas não funcionou e ainda estou em busca de respostas, se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço